# Fundamental group of compact manifolds with non-negative Ricci curvature and Bieberbach theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact n-dimensional Riemannian manifold with non-negative Ricci curvature. Then its universal cover $\tilde{M}$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^p\times N$ for some $p\leqslant n$ and $N$ compact. Consider the group $G$ of isometries on $N$ that are split off by the action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde{M}$.

**We know that $\pi_1(M)$ act discretely on $\tilde{M}$, why does G act discretely on N? Hence it's finite.**

Denote the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^p$ by $Iso(\mathbb{R}^p)$. Consider the projection map
$$
\pi_1(M) \to Iso(R^p),
$$
the kernel is $G$.
The image $H$ is a subgroup of $Iso(\mathbb{R}^p)$ acting discretely on $\mathbb{R}^p$. 
The Bieberbach theorem says that $H$ contains a normal free abelian subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^p$ such that $[H:\mathbb{Z}^p]<C$.

Let us prove this. Since any element $\alpha \in Iso(\mathbb{R}^p)$ is in the form: $\alpha(x)=Ax+a$, where $A\in O(p-1)$ is a rotation, $a\in \mathbb{R}^p$ is a translation. Consider the projection
$$
\alpha=(A,a) \in H \to A \in O(p-1).
$$
The kernel is a subgroup acting discretely on $\mathbb{R}^p$ by translation, it's $\mathbb{Z}^p$.

**Why is the image finite? i.e. Why does the rotation part act discretely on $\mathbb{R}^p$?**

Comment: The second question is part of Bieberbach's theorem (not in the way you state it). What more do you want?

Comment: If $M$ is a $2$-dimensional sphere endowed with the standard metric, then $M = N$ and the group of isometries won't act discretely on $N$.

Comment: @YCor:I try to prove that $H$ is contains an abelian group with finite index.

Comment: @HYL: Then the fundamental group is trivial.

Answer (score 5):

The group $G$ need not act discretely on $N$, e.g., consider $G=\mathbb Z$ acting on $S^2\times\mathbb R$ acting by an irrational rotation on the first factor and by translation on the second factor.

To learn more about these matters I suggest you read first Cheeger-Gromoll's paper on the soul theorem (which contains the above example of $\mathbb Z$-action on $S^2\times\mathbb R$), and then Wilking's paper [On fundamental groups of manifolds of nonnegative curvature. Differential Geom. Appl. 13 (2000), no. 2, 129–165]. In the latter Wilking shows that any nonnegatively curved metric as you describe can be deformed through nonnegatively curved metrics to the metric for which the $G$ action on $N$ factors through the action of a finite group.